# How to filter using concatenation of two columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have read in a parquet file and I would like to filter 
 rows using prepared dict.    There are two columns in the dataframe called col1 and col2 which are of type string. My dictionary has a set of strings in it and I want rows where the concatenation of the strings in columns col1 and col2 are in the dictionary. I tried

```python
df.filter((df['col1']+df['col2']) in my_dict)
```

but it seems that `df['col1']+df['col2']` is not a string even though that is the type of columns.

I also tried

```python
df.filter(lambda x: (x['col1']+df['col2']) in my_dict)
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Irrespectively of their contents, `df['col1']` and `df['col2']` are of type `pyspark.sql.column.Column`, and not of type string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there are 2 components in your issue:

1. The string column concatenation
2. The filtering using a dictionary

Regarding the first part - here is an example of string column concatenation using a toy dataframe:

```python
spark.version
# u'2.1.1'

from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit
df = spark.createDataFrame([("foo", 1), ("bar", 2)], ("k", "v"))
df.show()
# +---+---+
# |  k|  v|
# +---+---+
# |foo|  1|
# |bar|  2|
# +---+---+

df2 = df.select(concat(col("k"), lit(" "), col("v")).alias('joined_colname'))
df2.show()
# +--------------+ 
# |joined_colname|
# +--------------+
# |         foo 1|
# |         bar 2|
# +--------------+
```

Regarding the second part, you need the `.isin` method - not sure it will work with dictionaries, but it definitely works with lists (`['foo 1', 'foo 2']`) or sets (`{'foo 1', 'foo 2'}`):

```python
df2.filter(col('joined_colname').isin({'foo 1', 'foo 2'})).show() # works with lists, too
# +--------------+
# |joined_colname| 
# +--------------+
# |         foo 1|
# +--------------+
```

Hope this is helpful enough...

**EDIT** (after comment): to keep the joined column together with the columns of your initial `df`:

```python
df3 = df.withColumn('joined_colname', concat(col("k"), lit(" "), col("v")))
df3.show()
# +---+---+--------------+ 
# |  k|  v|joined_colname| 
# +---+---+--------------+
# |foo|  1|         foo 1|
# |bar|  2|         bar 2| 
# +---+---+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Does `df2 = df.select(concat(col("k"), lit(" "), col("v")).alias('joined_colname'))` also maintain all the other columns of `df`?

Comment: @eleanora you need to invoke `withColumn` - see edit